# Delphi Restricting a single instance of a program based on command line parameters

Tags: delphi, singleton, delphi-xe6

I know I have done this before but can't seem to remember how.

I have a program I have set up to run singleton using the mutex on the executable name.
unit GlobalSU;

```
interface
 function IsAppRunning: Boolean;

implementation

uses
 Windows, SysUtils, Forms;

function IsAppRunning: Boolean;
var
 rtn : Cardinal;
begin
  result := False;
  CreateMutex(nil, False, PWideChar(ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName)));
  rtn := GetLastError;
  if rtn = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS then
   result := True;
end;
```

The program accepts certain command line parameters that dictate what data to act on.  I don't want more than one instance of the program running with the same command line arguments.  But I do want to be able to start up a second instance with different arguments.

I did this about a year ago but can't remember how.  I modify the name with the command line parameters in the DPR and then test for it with the mutex.

I tried renaming Application.ExeName but it is read only so I must have been changing something else.

Below is code that won't compile but added to clarify what I want to do.
btw - the '##" is always the first two characters of the 3rd parameters but I test for it with a RegEx.

```
program EPRmailer;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  uMainMailer in 'uMainMailer.pas' {frmMainMailer},
  configXML in 'configXML.pas',
  GlobalSU in 'GlobalSU.pas',
  CVUtils in 'CVUtils.pas',
  QMConst in 'QMConst.pas',
  ServerAttachmentDMu in 'ServerAttachmentDMu.pas';

{$R *.res}
 var
   i : integer;
begin

  for i := 0 to ParamCount do
  if TestParam('##', ParamStr(i)) then
  Application.ExeName := Application.ExeName + '-' + ParamStr(i);

  if IsAppRunning then exit;

  Application.Initialize;
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := DebugHook <> 0;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := false;
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmMainMailer, frmMainMailer);
  frmMainMailer.RunEPR;

end.
```

Comment: Should the application `foo.exe -a -b` treated as being equal to `foo.exe -b -a` and `foo.exe -B -a`?

Comment: The parameter for the name of the mutex can be at most `MAX_PATH` long which is not enough e.g. for passing approx. 250 chars long (`MAX_PATH - 'EPRmailer'`) command line parameters. In such case your mutex creation fails, but not because of the error `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` and you'll return a wrong value from your function. To prevent this I would think of a hash here (after sorting the parameters).

Comment: If Application.Title is unique enough, it can be used instead of Application.ExeName, since it is much shorter and does not contain '\' characters.

Comment: I cannot see how your `IsAppRunning` (in its current form) could ever have been used in the way you describe. So I suspect that when you last used it to enforce single-instance based on parameters, it was implemented a little differently. Or perhaps you changed it to suit that requirement.

Answer (score 8):

You are using wrong approach. Instead of renaming `Application.ExeName`, you should send configurable string to your function that tests for duplicate applications.

```
function CreateSingleInstance(const InstanceName: string): boolean;
var
  MutexHandle: THandle;
begin
  MutexHandle := CreateMutex(nil, false, PChar(InstanceName));
  // if MutexHandle created check if already exists
  if (MutexHandle <> 0) then
    begin
      if GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS then
        begin
          Result := false;
          CloseHandle(MutexHandle);
        end
      else Result := true;
    end
  else Result := false;
end;

var
  MyInstanceName: string;
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  // Initialize MyInstanceName here
  ...
  if CreateSingleInstance(MyInstanceName) then
    begin
      // Form creation 
      ...
    end
  else Application.Terminate;
end.
```

Function CreateSingleInstance is meant to be used once in application because it allocates mutex that will remain active until application terminates and then Windows will automatically close mutex handle.

**Note:** if `MyInstanceName` exceeds `MAX_PATH` characters or contains backslash `'\'` characters function will fail

[CreateMutex documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This function will return always False if you pass there more than `MAX_PATH` long `InstanceName` value. Also that `PWideChar` cast is no good for old Delphi versions ;-) Actually, it's enough to write `Result := (CreateMutex(nil, False, PChar(InstanceName)) <> 0) and (GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS);` but the risk of exceeding the mutex name length remains.

Comment: Also, it will only work if you call `IsAppRunning()` one time, since the mutex is not being closed, so subsequent calls would detect `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.

Comment: @TLama I changed code, but I added a bit more complex check to make it more visible what is going on, including closing mutex handle though it is not necessary if function is used only for app startup

Comment: @RemyLebeau Since function is called in such context that it will not be called twice it would function properly even without explicit closing of the mutex handle. However I have changed that code and gave another name to the function to make its purpose more obvious.

Comment: Hm, that backslash restriction is even worse for command line parameters.

Comment: MyInstanceName := ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName) + '-' + ParamStr(i);

  if CreateSingleInstance(MyInstanceName) then
    begin
      Application.CreateForm(TfrmMainMailer, frmMainMailer);
      //frmMainMailer.RunEPR;
      showMessage(MyInstanceName+' be running');
    end
  else Application.Terminate;

I like this better since I want to protect the process, even if another program in a different directory (with the same ##CompanyName) is called.
Thanks all

Comment: The problem with that approach is that you are using the process filename as part of the mutex name.  Think of what happens if the user simply makes a copy of the EXE file and/or changes its filename before then starting the app.  Multiple instances will then be allowed to run.  Better to use something more unique, like a guid.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Reminder: OP does want to allow multiple instances. Just not with the same command-line parameters. I don't see how a GUID would help here? Dalija has pointed out how to change the design slightly so that `IsAppRunning` can support the the requirement. But in addition: OP should probably sort the parameters (if the answer to Sir Rufo's comment is "yes") and hash them.